# O que Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill(); faz?

Tags: c#, console-application

Estou fazendo um programa, nele tenho que parar a execução de uma tela com uma condição.
Encontrei uma maneira de fazer isso aqui pela internet, mas nao quero só copiar, quero entender!

Segue o código:

```
public void PararExecucaoERetornarAoMenu()
        {
            var menu = new TelaMenu(repositorioPessoa);
            menu.Executar();
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        }
```

Para o que serve?
Em que situações usar?
Há outras funções que fazem a mesma coisa que ele?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente voce pega o processo recorrente com `Process.GetCurrentProcess()` e mata o mesmo com o `Kill()`, como se voce abrisse o gerenciador de tarefas e forçasse a finalização do mesmo nesse caso o processo recorrente seria `menu.Executar();`

Comment: Entendi, entao pro meu caso não é usual, pois ele mata todo o programa e não somente a execução de uma classe onde ele foi posto.

Como eu poderia fazer isso sem matar o processo do programa inteiro?

vou usar meu exemplo: tenho a classe TelaCadatro e nela tenho campos(nome, sexo, idade, nacionalidade), quero que o processo dessa classe pare se for colocado "SAIR" em algum dos campos e retorne a TelaMenu

Comment: não tenho certeza mas voce pode tentar utilizar o `Close();` exemplo na doc: 
  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: vi algo parecido tambem em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077961/how-to-delete-an-instance-of-a-class